# How do I change the grayscale of an iframe using DOM (*object*.style)?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change the grayscale to 100% of an iframe after a certain button is pressed. Here is a basic version of a part of my code:

HTML:

```
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p class = "text">
                                Would you like to turn the colors into black and white?
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type = "radio" id = "blackandwhiteyes" name = "blackandwhite" value = "blackandwhiteyes" required>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type = "radio" id = "blackandwhiteno" name = "blackandwhite" value = "blackandwhiteno" required>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
blackandwhiteyes.onclick = function () {
    numiframe.style.(*What do I enter here to make the grayscale change?*);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have control of the iframes source code? If not you really can't without getting real hacky, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe). If you have control of the iframe you can use CSS to change the the entire page to [greyscale](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgyg2a4r/19/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `filter` CSS property.

```
numiframe.style.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
```

See also: [grayscale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/grayscale)